# I don't know how it works?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

What is the output of following function for start pointing to first node of following linked list?

1->2->3->4->5->6

```
void fun(struct node* start) 
{ 

  if(start == NULL) 

    return; 

  printf("%d  ", start->data);  



  if(start->next != NULL ) 

    fun(start->next->next); 

  printf("%d  ", start->data); 
}
```

Comment: What do you think the output is and why? Note the order of the print and the recursive call.

Comment: Why don't you run it yourself and see the output it provides?

Comment: You can use [Ideone](https://ideone.com/) or [OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) to test code. If you have specific problem, like writing main(), specifically ask that.

Comment: The way to answer this question is to act like the computer, but on paper. Write down the initial list. Start tracing the code. When you get to the `printf` statement, write down what you think will be output. When you encounter the recursive call, add the current location and value to the stack. When you encounter the function return, pop from the stack. This exercise is a test to see if you understand how recursion works.

Comment: A good place to start is to use a list that has only one node. Then one with two nodes. Then one with three nodes. Simulate the computer's operation.

Answer (score -1):

As a fellow new contributor, I'm going to give you a break and provide the code to create a linked list, and the one modification Blaze suggested.  I'm not overly swift at C, so there are probably better implementations.  Hope this will help you and/or others.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "malloc.h"

struct node {
    int data;
    node* nextNode;
};

void fun(struct node* start)
{

    printf("%d", start->data);        //  <===  this needs to be first
    if (start->nextNode == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    printf("->");
    fun(start->nextNode);
}

node* findLastNode(struct node* previousNode)
{

    if (previousNode->nextNode == NULL) {
        return previousNode;
    }
    findLastNode(previousNode->nextNode);
}

void addNode(node* firstNode, int data)
{
    node* lastNode = NULL;
    node* nodePtr;

    nodePtr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    nodePtr->data = data;
    nodePtr->nextNode = NULL;

    if (firstNode->nextNode == NULL) {
        firstNode->nextNode = nodePtr;
    }
    else {
        lastNode = findLastNode(firstNode);
        lastNode->nextNode = nodePtr;
    }

}

int main()
{
    node firstNode;

    firstNode.nextNode = NULL;
    addNode(&firstNode, 1);
    addNode(&firstNode, 2);
    addNode(&firstNode, 3);
    addNode(&firstNode, 4);
    addNode(&firstNode, 5);
    addNode(&firstNode, 6);

    fun(firstNode.nextNode);
    printf("\n");
}
```